# How can I add a class to an element if an anchor inside a list item is active?

Tags: html, jquery

I have this structure:

```
<div id="prev-button">
  Previous
</div>
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li class="" data-skus="">
    <a class="thumbnail active">
      <img src=""></a>
  </li>
  <li class="" data-skus="">
    <a class="thumbnail">
      <img src=""></a>
  </li>
  <li class="" data-skus="">
    <a class="thumbnail">
      <img src=""></a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="next-button">
  Next
</div>
```

I need to add `new-class` to `id="prev-button"` when the first `<li>` has `active` class on its `<a>` child.

When first anchor doesn't have `active` class, remove the `new-class` from `id="prev-button"`

Also, when last list item has `active` class added to its child anchor, same `new-class` has to be added to `id="next-button"`.

I tried to add `new-class` to the parent list item when the anchor has `active` class and is not working.

```
if ($('.thumbnail').is(".active")) {
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: Protip: Use actual button elements for accessibility, or at least apply proper [ARIA roles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role).

Comment: Where are you calling that code? Please revise your post to show a functioning snippet. jQuery is available right from the snippet editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.index` to know the sequential order of the selected element. So depending on which one is active, the following expression:

```
$(".thumbnail.active").parent().index()
```

will evaluate to 0, 1 or 2.

Then with `toggleClass()` you can choose to set the "new-class" on the first button when, and only if, that index is 0, and something similar can be done for the other button.

Here is a demo:

```js
// The argument to this function determines how the current selection should move:
// 0: don't move it; just apply the necessary CSS
// 1: move it down
// -1: move it up
function select(dir) {
    let last = $(".thumbnail").length - 1;
    let curr = $(".thumbnail.active").parent().index() + dir;
    if (curr >= 0 && curr <= last) {
        $(".thumbnail").removeClass("active").eq(curr).addClass("active");
        $("#prev-button").toggleClass("disabled", curr == 0);
        $("#next-button").toggleClass("disabled", curr == last);
    }
}

$("#prev-button").click(select.bind(0, -1));
$("#next-button").click(select.bind(0, 1));
select(0); // initialise also on page load
```

```css
#prev-button, #next-button {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active { background: yellow }
#prev-button.disabled, #next-button.disabled { background: silver }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prev-button">
  Previous
</div>
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li class="" data-skus="">
    <a class="thumbnail active">
      <img src="">first</a>
  </li>
  <li class="" data-skus="">
    <a class="thumbnail">
      <img src="">second</a>
  </li>
  <li class="" data-skus="">
    <a class="thumbnail">
      <img src="">third</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="next-button">
  Next
</div>
```

### Without `parent().index()`:

The above is quite sensitive to the document structure. Alternatively, you can use `index` with an argument, which works much like `indexOf` on arrays:

```js
// The argument to this function determines how the current selection should move:
// 0: don't move it; just apply the necessary CSS
// 1: move it down
// -1: move it up
function select(dir) {
    let $links = $(".thumbnail");
    let $active = $links.filter(".active");
    let curr = $links.index($active) + dir;
    let last = $links.length - 1;
    if (curr >= 0 && curr <= last) {
        $(".thumbnail").removeClass("active").eq(curr).addClass("active");
        $("#prev-button").toggleClass("disabled", curr == 0);
        $("#next-button").toggleClass("disabled", curr == last);
    }
}

$("#prev-button").click(select.bind(0, -1));
$("#next-button").click(select.bind(0, 1));
select(0); // initialise also on page load
```

```css
#prev-button, #next-button {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active { background: yellow }
#prev-button.disabled, #next-button.disabled { background: silver }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prev-button">
  Previous
</div>
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li class="" data-skus="">
    <a class="thumbnail active">
      <img src="">first</a>
  </li>
  <li class="" data-skus="">
    <a class="thumbnail">
      <img src="">second</a>
  </li>
  <li class="" data-skus="">
    <a class="thumbnail">
      <img src="">third</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="next-button">
  Next
</div>
```

Comment: When last list item has active class added to its child anchor, same new-class has to be added to id="next-button" -  Can we do this without using any index? This method is interfering with the jscarousel lite that i am using. Something like $('ul li:last-child a.active').... Thanks

Comment: As to your first phrase: I believe that is what my answer is doing when you run the snippet. As to your question: you can do this without `index()`. There is another signature of `index` where you pass an argument. It works completely different then, and may be what you are looking for. I added a second snippet that uses that idea.

Comment: I added the code and the carousel thumbs jumps from 2 in 2 and than 1 (since is last image) and also the disabled class is not added (the existing code already ads .disabled so i changed in your code to disabled1 and like i said, it is not adding the new class.  Do you know how to add a new class to the next button only when the last li has a child with .active ? $('ul li:last-child a.active') ---- what should be here to toggle new class for the next button?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but all I can say is that in the snippet it works. If your situation is different then I suggest you post a new question providing the code to reproduce the issue you have

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It is not doable to post a new code because the gallery is coming from html+php+jquery. I tried to get all relevant code and i failed to make a proper jsfiddle.

Comment: Php just produces html css and js, so just grab that. And jquery can be included in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to access the `id="prev-button"` with `$(this).parent().addClass("active");`? The parent would be the `li` element. Why not use `$("#prev-button")` to access the prev-button?

You can create a playground at Codepen.io to experiment, for example.
I have created one this which is the first fix for what you asked:
https://codepen.io/peter-krebs/pen/xxdxoPZ

https://api.jquery.com/ has tons of resources for you to read with example code. Don't be afraid to educate yourself, don't just guess how it works.